# Changing TextField's placeholder (hint) direction doesn't work

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, placeholder, gravity, hint

I have the following composable -

```kotlin
Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentSize(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            TextField(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f),
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
                    focusedContainerColor = getColorFromViewSystem(color = R.attr.colorSecondary),
                    unfocusedContainerColor = getColorFromViewSystem(color = R.attr.colorSecondary)
                ),
                textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(
                    textDirection = TextDirection.Content,
                ),
                value = searchTerm,
                onValueChange = { searchTerm ->
                    onSearchTermChanged(searchTerm)
                },
                placeholder = {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                        text = stringResource(id = R.string.search_hint),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.End
                    )
                }
            )
//          more composables...

        }
//      more composables...
    }
```

As you can see, on my placeholder variable (equivalent to hint at XML), I have a Text that I am trying to make it aligned to the end of my Text but it doesn't work. I am using RTL language if that matters, and here is the result -

[image]

My goal that the hint will move to the left side. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this behavior, you can use `TextDirection` from `TextStyle`. So changing the code it would like this:

```kotlin
placeholder = {
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        text = "Hint",
        style = TextStyle(
            textDirection = TextDirection.Rtl
        ),
        textAlign = TextAlign.End
    )
}
```

Note that there's also `TextDirection.ContentOrRtl`, as per documentation `Rtl` will always enable this behavior while `ContentOrRtl` will enable RTL when it detects RTL text on first character, so depending on your usecase you may prefer `ContentOrRtl`.

`TextDirection.ContentOrRtl` Doc:

> This value indicates that the text direction depends on the first strong directional character in the text according to the Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm. If no strong directional character is present, then Right to Left will be used as the default direction.

Comment: Thanks, already tried this solution but it doesn't work for some reason. Is there any kind of special behavior of a style of a Text inside a TextField that prevents it from moving to Start / End positions?

Comment: @AlonShlider I noticed you were using `Modifier.weight(1f)`, that doesn't do anything in this case, try using `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()` so that the `Text` will occupy the entire space available and the alignment should take effect.

Comment: Already tried that, didn't work. What worked for me is to wrap the Text with a Row, adding a Spacer with a 1f weight modifier that will push the text to the desired location